# GridView not conforming to Relativelayout alignment

Tags: java, android, layout, gridview, android-relativelayout

I'd like to right align this gridview so that it's flush against the right side of the screen, but it seems to always immediately follow whichever textview I set it to the right of. Not only that, but all of the textviews are displayed on top of each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/time_left"
              android:textSize="30sp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:id="@+id/time_left_label"/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/time_left"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@id/time_left_label"/>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/progress"
              android:textSize="30sp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@id/time_left"
              android:id="@+id/progress_label" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/progress"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@id/progress_label"/>
    <GridView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/main_grid"
              android:numColumns="2"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time_left_label"
              android:stretchMode="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a picture of what I want drawn quickly in paint!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXX5M.jpg

Comment: 1. the textviews are on top of each other because they are all left aligned. Use android:layout_toRightOf="" and they wont overlap.If
could you fire up paint and draw a picture of your desired layout we might have an easier time helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to right align this gridview

How exactly do you want it aligned? You mention what it does, but not what you want.

> it seems to...follow whichever textview I set it to the right of

Welll, you're using `layout_alignParentRight` and `layout_toRightOf`.

> the textviews are displayed on top of each other.

Placing your `TextViews` underneath each other won't stack them. You can use a `LinearLayout` with its `orientation` set to `vertical` or you could use `layout_below` to place them under each other.

Comment: I've made the changes to make the text not overlap. Thanks, I feel silly now for not thinking of that.